# Additional resource/ js files added by Kentico?

Tags: kentico

I view sourced a site I built with Kentico (v9) and noticed there're many js files added (sample list below) that I've never used or added myself in any of my templates. Is there a place/file where I can manage this listing? One of the resource file returns a 404, and the jquery-core is redundant (because I used and linked to a different jquery file in the master template)

**Edit: To clarify**, I've created the site from scratch myself using Portal Engine, so I know which files are in use/needed, but the system was set up by a different team, so I'm not sure about those resources and how they got in there.

```
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=tOC6-8tIvm-6k-UeWp5sUWPuNRu5mtP3WV2AZEfL9nI2sRmgKd5MnlDVvBjdzVe9wwB392nFnls5rAu3Ry5vq1yWL8h_-l2ltMTIVb8BU3E1&amp;t=637346642097037378" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?scriptfile=%7e%2fCMSScripts%2fWebServiceCall.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?scriptfile=%7e%2fCMSScripts%2fRequireJS%2frequire.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?scriptfile=%7e%2fCMSScripts%2fRequireJS%2fconfig.js&amp;resolvemacros=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?scriptfile=%7e%2fCMSScripts%2fcms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?scriptfile=%7e%2fCMSScripts%2fjquery%2fjquery-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of these are things added by various Controls (webparts), not much you can do about it, it's the nature of WebForms that in order for certain things to work it needs to pull in the javascript this way.